# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.ElasticsearchPersistentEntity.getInstanceCreatorMetadata()'

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using "spring-data-elasticsearch" but
getting the below error while using **findById(id)** in spring data elasticsearch.

Note: save/update is working fine.

Can someone please help me here?

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.data.mapping.InstanceCreatorMetadata org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.ElasticsearchPersistentEntity.getInstanceCreatorMetadata()'
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.readEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:311)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:258)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:217)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:161)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:83)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:745)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate$ReadSearchDocumentResponseCallback.doWith(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:778)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate$ReadSearchDocumentResponseCallback.doWith(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:763)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.search(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:404)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchOperations.searchOne(SearchOperations.java:123)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.execute(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:132)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.findByDataSourceId(Unknown Source)
```

**please find the maven dependency that I am using**

```
<!-- Elastic Search -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: that method is in spring-data-commons:2.7.0 which should be pulled in from Spring Boot 2.7.0 and spring-data-elasticsearch:4.4.0


Can you check which versions are _really_ used in your project. It seems that an older version of spring-data-commons is used.